# How to use local project files in build.rs script?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How do I use local files without including their absolute paths in `build.rs`? I have, for example `let proto_file_glob_paths: Paths = glob("../proto/**/*.proto").unwrap();`.

I am using relative paths in my `build.rs`, because I don't want to hardcode the absolute path of files, so that it works on other developer machines. The build works fine with `cargo build` and `cargo run`, but **not** `cargo publish`. This is because the **working directory/path is different when `cargo publish` is run**.

### In `cargo build`, the `env::current_dir()` is:

```
project_name/target/debug/build/project_name-70e21ac88134b5a1/build-script-build
```

### In `cargo publish`, the `env::current_dir()` is:

```
project_name/target/package/project_name-x.y.z/target/debug/build/project_name-xxxxxxx/build-script-build
```

I don't know of any environment variables I can use to access the directory of `build.rs`, or `src/`, so that I can create a relative/absolute path dynamically. Even `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR` is different for `build` and `publish`.

---

**Project specifics:** I've got other lines of code to generate the rust code using other packages, and this works fine in `cargo build` and `cargo run`.

Comment: Are this local project files stored inside the crate root directory? If not, this is probably impossible, since even if you publish successfully, they won't be in the crate tarball, and the build will break on the machine pulling it.

Comment: Thanks for your time , that's an interesting problem . Right now, they are **not** in the crate root, but next to the crate folder. I have a repository that has multiple root folders, one for each language (eg javascript, python, rust) which all share these local files.

Comment: I'd be happy to move the files using some shell script in combination with a gitignore file though, so we can assume that the files are present in the crate root directory.

Comment: I tried moving the files into the crate root, `cargo build` works, but not `cargo publish`. It's not able to find the files during publish, again because the current_dir is different

Comment: Are you sure the files are [included in the package](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-exclude-and-include-fields)?

Comment: Thanks @ColonelThirtyTwo, that has fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some very helpful prompting from @Cerberus and then from @ColonelThirtyTwo, I just:

- copied the local files into the crate root. I wrote a script to do this before running `cargo build`. Of course, I needed to update the relative path to use `proto/` instead of `../proto/`.
- added the `proto` directory to the `gitignore` file
- and added the `proto` directory to `package.include` in `Cargo.toml` because it would not be included as it is gitignored:

```
[package]
...
include = ["**/*.rs", "Cargo.toml", "Cargo.lock", "config.json", "proto"]
```

My mistakes were that:

- I assumed `../proto` should work, but as Cerberus explained, it won't. **Since the files would be missing for the users of the crate.**
- I didn't add the `proto` file to `include` in `Cargo.toml`